# turning items chck state off when they are already turned of

Tags: swift, cocoa

i have a general about programing in general

lets say there is 
3 menu items and one of them is checked
and i need that when i click another one
it unchecks the currectly selected one

it would be easy to say

turn off everything exept the one that just got clicked

but then u ended up running a function
that turns off items that are already turned off

is this a problem in general?
does this take too much resources to do so?
i cant see any other way to not turn off 
things that are already turned off

Comment: "i have a general"  I suggest you look up your English dictionary about the word general as a noun.  You have plenty of grammatical mistakes and typos that make your English sentences nearly incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off every item before setting one is not an issue.

However if you still want to process only the checked item you can do it by using a conditional for loop or a map.

Here is the for loop example:

```
//Class representing the item.
class Item {
    var isChecked = false
}

//Array of 3 items.
var items: [Item] = [Item(), Item(), Item()]

//Function that should be called (as @IBAction) when an item is tapped.
func itemIsTapped(itemTag: Int) {
    selectItemAt(index: itemTag)
}
//Function that unselected the checked item and select the one that should be.
func selectItemAt(index: Int) {

    //This is the part where you UNCHECKED ONLY the CHECKED item.
    for item in items where item.isChecked {
        item.isChecked = false
    }

    items[index].isChecked = true
}
```

Comment: good answer, but isn't it a bit too much to ask for a check when we could just say turn them all off regardless of if they are already off? do u know which way profesional programer go far 1. turn them all of either way 2. check if off already

Comment: It depends on the situation but in this specific case I would say that it is more convenient and less verbose to set all of them to unchecked (even if they already are) and then to check the selected one. If you have a « didSet » statement that triggers a function when unchecking, my answer could be different. Anyway, computation ressources depend on the size of the array you iterate on, but to be honest, I’m pretty sure that computation time is not an issue in your case as they are really simple and short operations.